# Unity prefab issues

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, terrain

I have created a prefab of a Terrain.
I pass it on to script where it gets instantiated (hundreds of times).
The problem is that the prefab itself gets changed with every instantiation. (its name and its translation).
How do I prevent this?

Sample code :

```html
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class LandCrafter : MonoBehaviour {

 public Terrain parentPiece;
 public Terrain randomPiece;
 

 void Start () {

  for (int i = 0; i<=maxLandBlocks; i++) {
   if (currentPlacedBlocks.Count <= maxLandBlocks) {
    pieceList = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("randomTerrainPiece");
    LandCraft ();
   } else {
    randomPiece.name = "randomPieceOfLand";
    charCraft ();
   }
  }
 }
 

 void LandCraft(){

  someExistingLandPiece = (GameObject)pieceList [(int)Random.Range(0.0f,pieceList.Length)];
  test = someExistingLandPiece.transform.position;
 
   if (!currentPlacedBlocks.Contains (someExistingLandPiece.transform.position + Vector3.forward)) {
   Instantiate (randomPiece);
   randomPiece.name = "The" + i++;
   randomPiece.transform.position = someExistingLandPiece.transform.position + Vector3.forward;
   currentPlacedBlocks.Add (randomPiece.transform.position);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, you actually have to instantiate the prefab and "feed" that instance to the script. If you feed the prefab directly, everything you do automatically applies to it..